# jquery ui autocomplete positioning wrong

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

using jquery ui 1.8
trying autocomplete

Everything works apart from that the ui-menu isn't positioned under my input element, but rather in the top left corner.

Has anyone come across this problem?

Here's my html:

```
<div id="search">
    <div id="searchFormWrapper">
        <form method="post" name="searchForm" id="searchForm" action="/searchresults">
        <label for="searchPhrase" id="searchFor">
            Search for</label>
        <input name="searchPhrase" id="searchPhrase" type="text" />
        <label for="searchScope" id="searchIn">
            in</label>
        <select name="searchScope" id="searchScope">
            <option value="">All Shops</option>
            ...
        </select>
        <input type="image" name="submitSearch" id="submitSearch" src="/images/buttons/search.gif"
            alt="Search ..." />
        </form>
        <br class="clear" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my css:

```
#search
{
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 text-align:center;
 height:36px;
 line-height:36px;
 background:#666 url(/images/interface/info_bar_bg.gif) repeat-x top left;
 overflow:hidden;
 font-size:12px;
}
#searchFormWrapper
{
 width:520px;
 height:36px;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin:auto;
 padding:0;
}
label#searchFor
{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 width:80px;
 padding:0 5px 0 0;
 margin:0 0 0 0;
 text-align:right;
}
label#searchIn
{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 width:20px;
 padding:0 5px 0 0;
 margin:0 0 0 0;
 text-align:right;
}
#searchPhrase
{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 width:120px;
 margin:7px 0 0 0;
 padding:0;
}
#searchScope
{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 width:120px;
 margin:7px 0 0 0;
 padding:0;
}
#submitSearch
{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 margin:7px 0 0 10px;
 padding:0;
}
```

and here's my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#searchPhrase").autocomplete(
    {
        source: "/search?json",
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you're including the jQuery UI CSS files?

Comment: Yep. Checked that. The ui-menu list is all formatted correctly. Just not positioned right...

Comment: Do you have a link to a version to look at? I would suggest removing all CSS other than the CSS for the auto-complete to check it it's any other rules conflicting.

Comment: Ok, done that (removed all other CSS) and it's still showing at the top left corner instead of attaching itself to the input element ... hmm ... it's a step forward I guess...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Woohoo. Found the culprit:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery/132/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery/132/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery/100325/jquery.dimensions.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery/100325/jquery.tooltip.js"></script>
```

Don't include jquery.dimensions.js. I assume it's already in jquery-ui.js ... anyway, it fixed my problem.

For latest jqueryUI you now need to include jquery.ui.position.js

Comment: Oh man, with my project it was the other way round - I had to remove the old jquery.dimensions.pack.js, since "dimensions" is now part of jQuery.UI. Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: Unbelievable! I was going to start picking my CSS apart until I found this post! Cheers!

Comment: This one reminded me that my jQuery 1.8.0.min and the UI 1.8.10 do not match.  Pointing to the correct UI version (1.8.23) solved the problem.

Answer (score 16):

I simply changed my jquery-ui.min.js to the latest version and it fixed the positioning.

from 1.8.16 to 1.8.23 and it worked!

Comment: I was using jquery-ui 1.8.18 and upgraded to 1.8.23 and it fixed my issue.

Comment: Updating to v.1.9.2 broke my code. Updating from 1.8.17 to 1.8.23 fixed my issue. Older versions can be found at jQuery UI github: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/releases

Comment: Thank you ! Work like charm :)

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar issue, and after searching I found out I was missing a JS to fix this. In case someone stops by ensure to have a the "jquery.ui.position.js" script called as well.

See http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ under dependencies:
UI Core
UI Widget
UI Position

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't have dimensions.js included, but I was still seeing the misplaced autocomplete. Once I added the position.js, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Simply updating to the latest JQueryUI did the trick for me.
I started having this issue after I switched to Twitter Bootstrap (and the latest JQuery I think too).

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but just had this issue myself and fixed it another way.

I had updated jQuery, which caused the menu to appear at `left:0;` `top:0;` on the `window`, rather than nicely below my input.

Updating jQuery UI fixed it instantly.  Hope this is of use to someone.

Answer (score 3):

Update Jquery UI and jQuery scripts in your project, it will resolve any conflict and issue will get fix.

Answer (score 1):

put

```
position: relative;
```

inside of

```
#searchFormWrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

Another similar issue, if you're using a CDN to serve your jquery files, make sure you use a specific version, i.e.:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/
```

Rather than the 'latest' version:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/
```

This will take away the possibility of conflicts in future releases of jquery, which can often break an app when the 'latest' version on jquery is updated on the CDN.