# How do I align jQuery autocomplete properly?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

This is most unusual. I'm implementing jquery autocomplete on an input field on my site but the suggestions are not appearing under the input field as I type. Instead they are showing in the far right corner of the html document. Is there a special class that I need to apply here to make this work?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="js/css/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];


        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
        #main{
            width: 200px;
            margin-bottom: 200px auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <input id="tags">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Something else is going on. I tried your code in Chrome, Firefox and IE7-8. It was properly aligned in all of them.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice that's different on yours than mine is that we have set the textbox class to class="ui-autocomplete-input"

Comment: Found this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560205/jquery-ui-autocomplete-positioning-wrong

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The jQuery version wasn't high enough. It needs to 1.5

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-autocomplete{
      left:632.5px !important;
      width:305px !important;
  }
```

Use this in your css to align your autocomplete. Change the left and width according to your needs