# Using CJuiAutoComplete with jQuery 1.8.0 renders autocomplete list at top=0, left=0

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, yii

I am using the yii framework and am testing the [CJuiAutoComplete](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiAutoComplete) feature which uses [jQuery UI's Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).
If I use version 1.6.1 which shipped with my version of yii the Autocomplete field works perfectly fine. However, if I switch to jQuery 1.8.0 the rendering of the list containing the options to choose from doesn't seem right. I observed that running 1.6.1 the list gets set a top and left value within the style parameter. These values however are zero if running 1.8.0.
Did anyone else experience this? What would be a good way of fixing this?
I guess I could manually set these values but would prefer jQuery to handle this :)
Please let me know if you need to see any code.

Comment: Ran into the same problem, rolling back jquery to 1.7.2 works with jquery ui 1.8.2+, still searching for a proper solution... I found this: [jquery ui autocomplete positioning wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560205/jquery-ui-autocomplete-positioning-wrong#answer-2585676) however, in my app, adding jquery.ui.position.js only aligns the `left` value correctly, the `top` values is still 0, which aligns the suggestions to the top of the screen still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, with ui 1.8.2+ you need to include the following UI files:

`UI Core`,
`UI Widget`, and
`UI Position`

To include them in yii, simple call them using CClientScript:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile('//jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.23/ui/jquery.ui.position.js');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile('//jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.23/ui/jquery.ui.core.js');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile('//jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.23/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js');
```

Not perfect, as I'd assume Yii should include them by default, but it does work.

Thanks to Chris for his answer here: [jquery ui autocomplete positioning wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560205/jquery-ui-autocomplete-positioning-wrong#answer-7379634)

Comment: `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile('//jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.23/ui/jquery.ui.widgets.js');` should be `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile('//jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.23/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js');` Thank you very much for your response :)