# Wrong jQuery autocomplete positioning after upgrade from jQuery 1.6.2 to 1.8.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I was using jQuery 1.6.2 and everything with autocomplete was great.

However I needed to upgrade jQuery to the latest version 1.8.1 because of other scripts and autocomplete suddenly started to appear in left: 0; and top: 0; position (in the top left screen corner)

Then I have searched the internet and followed this topic here:

[jquery ui autocomplete positioning wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560205/jquery-ui-autocomplete-positioning-wrong)

And really, after upgrading jQuery UI to the latest version and adding position.js to header the left position is calculated OK, but still top position is wrong and 0 instead of e.g. 224px.

If I switch back to jQuery 1.6.2 (just change in my header the name of the file to load) the autocomplete works again great and it's on the right spot under input box.

But the problem is that I have to update my jQuery because there are other things on my website that need the latest jQuery 1.8.1 version.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried setting the position manually?

Comment: You could do with showing the HTML, CSS and jQuery related to the code/DOM with the problem.

Comment: It has nothing to do with html. It is a jQuery bug

Comment: Do you have a sample jsfiddle? It's working find in the [demo pages](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)?  Though that is using jquery 1.8.0...

Comment: I agree with @Orbling! Post somw html, css and jQuery!

Comment: @Derfder this has a great deal to do with HTML, and CSS. jQuery is a DOM library after all.

Comment: Did you update your jQuery UI CSS references when you updated the javascript reference?

Answer (score 0):

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WpeTf/1/) to show it is working with jquery 1.8.2 and jquery ui with no further bug fixing.