# How to set my jQuery UI autocomplete results under input with `id="drugs"`?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

How to set my jQuery UI autocomplete results under input with `id="drugs"` ? At the moment I have it in the upper left corner.

```
<form method="GET" action="/search/">
    <input type="text" id="drugs" name="drugs">
</form>
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#drugs").autocomplete({
    source: "/api/get_drugs/",
    minLength: 1,
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Could you post the jQuery code you use to initialize the autocomplete? and any relevant css? It would also help if you could create an example at jsfiddle.net

Comment: can we have some test data for the source rather than a url

Comment: Have you including the jQuery UI CSS files?

Comment: @sangramparmar Yes, this work fine but result are on the left upper corner, not under my form field

Comment: check this i think same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560205/jquery-ui-autocomplete-positioning-wrong

Comment: This is solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13179770/2661413 :)

Comment: I changed jQ UI from 1.8.16 to 1.8.23. Thanks you all, thanks @sangramparmar