# Autocomplete always on top left

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using autocomplete in one of my project and it gives me the results at the `top -left` of the page and if I saw in console it gives me

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new p.fn.init(a,b,c)} has no method 'curCSS'
```

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of it?

I get my autocomplete using:

```
$("#state_auto").autocomplete({            
   source: site_url + "content/user/state",
   minLength: 1,
   select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#iStateId").val(ui.item.id);
        //console.log(ui.item);
   }
});
```

Comment: Are you using the `position` object in your call?

Comment: No iam just giving like my edit

Comment: Can you show how you execute the autocomplete and when you are giving it an edit

Comment: Results are coming correctly

Comment: Anything abnormal on the page like an `iframe` or `modal` dialog?

Comment: Some say in this post you need `jquery.ui.position.js` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560205/jquery-ui-autocomplete-positioning-wrong

Comment: @Gautam3164 I would verify that your theme isn't messed up. Maybe pull a new one from the jQuery site and test it. It seems like something regarding the cursor position (CurCSS), and I would think that points straight to the theme.

Comment: What version of jQuery do you use ? `curCSS()` was a jQuery function, which was removed (in 1.8 if I am correct).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [from this bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11921), that some versions have this problem where others do not. You may want to read through it and see if there's a version that will work out for you.