# jQuery autocomplete display issue

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I use jQuery autocomplete plugin and until today it worked really well. But I have made some changes to current code (there were lots of improvements and I can't track which code update have broken my autocomplete), and now it shows very unusual display issue.

When I enter company name in input text, autocomplete results are shown in left upper corner of website:

[image: Autocomplete display issue]

Maybe someone had similar problem?

**UPDATE:**

*jQuery:*

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags2 = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $real_companies) . '"]' ?>;
    $( "#companies_for_tabs" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags2,
      select: function (a, b) {
        $(this).val(b.item.value);
        $("#extra-reason").show(400);
        $("#recommend-company-href").attr("onclick","document.forms['recommend-company-from-events'].submit();");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

*HTML:*

```
<form action="recommend_from_events.php" method="post" class="advanced-form" id="recommend-company-from-events">
<input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Who you want to recommend?" autocomplete="off" id="companies_for_tabs">
<textarea name="extra" style="display: none;" placeholder="Why you recommend? (optional)" maxlength="300" id="extra-reason"></textarea></td></tr>
<a class="save-button" id="recommend-company-href"><span>Recommend company</span></a>
</form>
```

Comment: It's impossible to provide any feedback with the (lack of) information here. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560205) as it describes something similar to your screenshot and is also a good example of [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an answerable question on SO

Comment: Sorry for that, mithunsatheesh and blgt.
I updated my post.

Comment: But I think the problem could be with some other code, maybe other plugins or inappropriate CSS or something. That's why me at first thought there is no need for more information, code. It is enough information now? :)

Comment: did you remove the relative positioning from the container div? or change the autocomplete dropdown positioning from absolute to fixed?

Comment: Pete, no, I didn't remove.

Comment: @PauliusVitkus Nothing wrong with the provided code (except the malformatted html, but presumably that happened while you were trimming it). Did you try the dependency solutions in the question linked above?

Comment: what is the `</td></tr>` for at the end of the lines?

Comment: blgt, now I am looking at your link. I think problem will be there - I will write if it was helpful.

Comment: Pete, sorry, I updated my code. All this form was included into table, tr, td, but I removed all of that, that for you would be more simple to look at code.

Comment: By the way, jQuery tooltips also doesn't work like it used to work. So, definitely, problem is in separate pieces of code, which "conflict each other".